# Remove HTML tags in specific tags in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'd like to make a SQL script to remove for exemple all `<strong> and </strong>` tags which are inside a title `<hX></hX>` tag.

I want to replace all occurences like `<h4><strong>Some text</strong></h4>` with `<h4>Some text</h4>`,
but only if in a H tag and without losing content of course.

I tried many things like the REGEXP_REPLACE and REGEXP_SUBSTR but I'm stuck with something like `REGEXP_REPLACE(myfield, "<h\\d>.*<strong>.*<\/strong>.*<\/h\\d>", "")` which replaces all match.

Comment: This is not something that regular expressions are good at.

Comment: I can't think of any easy way to do this in SQL.

Comment: This is literally what XSLT is for.

Comment: CSS to the rescue?

Comment: I guess my only option is using advanced SQL like cursors ...

Answer (score -1):

I use php to strip info out:  preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['username']); // filter everything but letters and numbers. It can be modified for specific phrases and characters.  I know it isn't SQL but it is something.  Also in Javascript, you can use an innerHTML command that pulls the text only out from within tags >Text<

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for a SQL solution